# SIGACTION with Roslaunch - Use in a TCP server

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I am currently working on integrating a TCP communication between ROS and a web application. I made my own TCP code using sockets in C. In order to be able to close this cleanly, I would like to be able to use sigaction, however it seems roslaunch prevents the process to receive the signals.
Is it normal or am I wrong?
Here is a link to the code I made :
https://github.com/RemiRigal/BathyBoatNav/blob/tcp_fix/src/tcp_serveur.cpp
Without ROS it seems to work fine !

I am using ROS Kinetic on a Linux Mint Mate 18.3 if it can help you understand.

Thanks for your help guys !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282423/sigaction-with-roslaunch---use-in-a-tcp-server/) by [lallemfa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33650/lallemfa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this informative thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/42134/how-are-signals-handled-by-roslaunch/), `roslaunch` handles `SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL`, but not `SIGACTION`. I've confirmed by scanning the latest code from https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/lunar-devel/tools/roslaunch that sigaction is not particularly handled.

```
$ git branch
* lunar-devel
$ git log -1
commit 283818529002c6d37e8b9ec554a17b40c6075c20
Author: nano-meter <pjoejoejoe@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 5 22:47:14 2018 +0200

    Add substitution when loading yaml files (#1354)
    
    * Add substitution when loading yaml files
    
    like in #1051
    
    * Add tests
$ ack-grep -A 1 -i sigaction .
$
```

Btw, just wondering if you're aware of some existing ROS packages that provide TCP communication. For websocket there is http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_server

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0